# Jumping to a Heading from Org-Agenda view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to jump from Agenda view to a particular Heading in an org file. The Heading has nothing to do with the items currently displayed in the Agenda.

If my buffer was an org file, I'd simply use `C-u C-c C-w` (refile to hop to a sub-tree without moving current subtree). However, this key binding does not work from Agenda view. <strike>I tried `M-x org-goto-interface`. However, the command `org-goto-interface` was not available when in Agenda view.</strike>

Comment: Are you sure about your claim about C-u C-x C-w?  Are you sure org-goto-interface is a command at all?  What version of Org are you using?

Comment: sorry, I meant to write `C-u C-c C-w`. The command is to refile with a `C-u` modifier to jump to a heading *without* moving current entry. I corrected the original post.

Comment: The outcome of C-h k C-c C-w could be of interest, I think.